# In SwiftUI recurring Stacks simplifying

Tags: swiftui, modifier

For MacOS I use the following code many times to create forms. I really like to create a modifier or extension to make it more simplified.

```
HStack{
    VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
         Text("Account Number").font(.headline)
         TextField("", text: $selectedBankAccount.accountNumber, prompt: Text("AccountNumber"))
    }
}
.frame(width: 450 )
```

I would love to see something like:

```
struct FormStackModifier: ViewModifier {
    var width : CGFloat
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                content
            }
        }
        .frame(width: width)
    }
}

// and use it like
ModifiedContent( 
   content: VStack { Text("Account Name").font(.headline)
                            TextField("", text: $selectedBankAccount.accountName, prompt: Text("AccountName"))},
   modifier: FormStackModifier(width: 450)
)
```

But I need stil the extra VStack in content.

Is there a to solve this and a way to make this neat?

Comment: I have no idea as to how you are using FormStackModifier.  Where does an actor named 'ModifiedContent' come from?

Comment: @ElTomato See [`ModifiedContent`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/modifiedcontent).

Comment: Oops...  I'm sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Group` is a view that does nothing but groups views together, allowing you to use multiple views as a single view. Unlike `VStack`, it doesn't enforce a particular layout on the views or do anything like that.

You can replace the `VStack` with `Group`.

```
ModifiedContent( 
   content: 
       Group { 
           Text("Account Name").font(.headline)
           TextField("", text: $selectedBankAccount.accountName, prompt: Text("AccountName"))
       },
   modifier: FormStackModifier(width: 450)
)
```

Using `ModifiedContent` like this is rather inconvenient. I recommend adding an extension on `View` that applies the `FormStackModifier`.

```
extension View {
    func formStack(width: CGFloat) -> some View {
        modifier(FormStackModifier(width: width))
    }
}

// usage:

Group { 
    Text("Account Name").font(.headline)
    TextField("", text: $selectedBankAccount.accountName, prompt: Text("AccountName"))
}
.formStack(width: 450)
```

---

Alternatively, instead of a `ViewModifier`, you can make your own `View` called `FormStack`:

```
struct FormStack<Content: View>: View {
    let width : CGFloat
    let content: Content
    
    init(width: CGFloat, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.width = width
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                content
            }
        }
        .frame(width: width)
    }
}

// usage:

FormStack(width: 450) { 
    Text("Account Name").font(.headline)
    TextField("", text: $selectedBankAccount.accountName, prompt: Text("AccountName"))
}
```